# Slide Jquery Puro

Tags: jquery, slide

```js
var conter = 0;
qtos = $(".tns-carousel li").length/3;
max = qtos * -14.2857;

$("#next").click(function(e){
    conter--;
    counter = conter * 14.2857;
    if (counter == max){
        counter = 0;
        conter = 0;
    }
    $("#conter_li").html(counter.toFixed(4) + " | " + conter);
    $(".tns-carousel").css("transform","translate3d("+counter.toFixed(4)+"%, 0px, 0px)");
});

$("#prev").click(function(e){
    conter++;
    counter = conter * 14.2857;
    
    if (conter > 0){
        counter = max + (counter * conter);
    }

    $("#conter_li").html(counter.toFixed(4) + " | " + conter);
    $(".tns-carousel").css("transform","translate3d("+counter.toFixed(4)+"%, 0px, 0px)");
});
```

```css
.performa-powersliderPopupecn1ml571r{position:fixed;top:calc(50% - 300px);left:calc(50% - 400px);display:none;width:800px;height:550px;background: #fff;z-index:100000000;animation-name: bounceIn;animation-duration: 450ms;animation-timing-function: linear;animation-fill-mode: forwards;animation-delay: 0s;-webkit-border-radius: 0px;-moz-border-radius: 0px;border-radius: 0px;}.performa-powerslider-close-intent{height: 40px;width: 40px;right: -20px;top: -20px;position: absolute;background: #000;border: 3px solid #fff;border-radius: 1000px;cursor: pointer;}.performa-powerslider-close-intent span{font-family: calibri, sans-serif;color: #fff;font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 38px;padding: 11px;top: 0px;vertical-align: middle;position: relative;box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;}.performa-powersliderPopupImgecn1ml571r{position:relative;float:lefttop:0px;left:0px;-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;-moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;border-top-left-radius: 0px;border-top-right-radius: 0px;}.performa-powersliderPopupFadeecn1ml571r{position:fixed;left:0px;top:0px;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;background:#000;opacity:0.7;display:none;z-index:99999999;}.performa-powerslider-bounce {-webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;animation: bounce 2s infinite;}@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn {0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0); }40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); }60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-15px); }}@-moz-keyframes bounceIn {0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0); }40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); }60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-15px); }}@keyframes bounceIn {0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);-moz-transform: translateY(0);-ms-transform: translateY(0);-o-transform: translateY(0);transform: translateY(0);}40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);-moz-transform: translateY(-30px);-ms-transform: translateY(-30px);-o-transform: translateY(-30px);transform: translateY(-30px);}60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);-moz-transform: translateY(-15px);-ms-transform: translateY(-15px);-o-transform: translateY(-15px);transform: translateY(-15px);}}.performa-powerslider-content-exit-intent {width:100%;position:absolute;overflow:hidden;}.powerSlider-exit-brand {    position: absolute;    bottom: -25px;       float: right;    width: 100%;}.powerSlider-exit-brand img {float: right;}.prevBtn {    position: absolute;    top: calc(50% - 25px);    left: 20px;    width: 30px;    height: 30px;    transform: rotate(45deg);    border: none;    background-color: transparent;    border-bottom: 4px solid #6b6b6b;    border-left: 4px solid #6b6b6b;}.nextBtn {    position: absolute;    top: calc(50% - 25px);    right: 20px;    width: 30px;    height: 30px;    transform: rotate(45deg);    border: none;    background-color: transparent;    border-top: 4px solid #6b6b6b;    border-right: 4px solid #6b6b6b;}.nextBtn:focus,.prevBtn:focus {    outline: none;}/*******************************
FIX LAYOUT CONTAINER EXIT INTENT
*******************************/
.performa-item-exit a:hover, .performa-item-exit a:visited, .performa-item-exit a:link, .performa-item-exit a:active, .performa-item-exit a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}

.performa-powersliderPopupk4s2oxsup9 {
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(50% - 300px);
    left: calc(50% - 400px);
    display: none;
    width: 800px;
    height: 550px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 100000000;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-duration: 450ms;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao {
    padding: 15px  10px !important;    
    border-radius: 20px !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    width: 900px !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    margin: auto;
}

.performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao > img {
    border-radius: 20px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center top;
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}

.performa-powersliderPopupImgk4s2oxsup9 {
    position: relative;
    float: lefttop:0px;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}

powerslider *, powerslider :after, powerslider :before {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    line-height: 1;
    list-style: none;
    quotes: none;
    content: '';
    content: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.performa-powerslider-content-exit-intent {
    width: auto !important;
    position: relative !important;
    margin: 130px 30px 0 !important;
    overflow: unset !important;
}

.performa-powerslider-close-intent {
    height: 25px !important;
    width: 25px !important;
    right: 10px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    border: unset !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

.performa-powerslider-close-intent span {
    font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 11px;
    top: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.performa-powerslider-close-intent span {
    color: #d62598 !important;
}

.performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao .tns-controls button[data-controls=prev] {
    left: -25px !important;
}

.performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao .tns-controls button[data-controls=next] {
    right: -25px !important;
}

#pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf-iw {
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.tns-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tns-controls {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.tns-outer {
    position: relative;
}

#pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf > .tns-item {
    width: calc(4.7619%);
}

#pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf > .tns-item {
    font-size: 14px;
}


.tns-controls button {
    position: absolute;
    background: 0 0;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    border-left: 2px solid;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 40%;
    z-index: 1;
    outline: 0;
}

.tns-controls button[data-controls=prev] {
    left: 15px;
}

.tns-controls button[data-controls=next] {
    right: 15px;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao .tns-controls button {
    color: #d62598 !important;
    width: 25px !important;
    height: 25px !important;
    border-bottom: 4px solid !important;
    border-left: 4px solid !important;
    border-radius: unset !important;
    background: transparent !important;
}

.performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao .tns-controls button:before {
    box-shadow: unset !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    border-radius: unset !important;
    color: transparent !important;
}

/****************
**SLIDER VITRINE**
****************/
.performa-exit-ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.performa-exit-ul .performa-item-exit {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.performa-item-exit a:hover,
.performa-item-exit a:visited,
.performa-item-exit a:link,
.performa-item-exit a:active,
.performa-item-exit a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}

.performa-exit-box {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    margin-right: 20px;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.performa-exit-box:hover {
}

.performa-exit-box a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.performa-flags-exit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.performa-flag-discount-exit {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 65px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #000;
    font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
}

.performa-image-exit {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.performa-image-exit img:first-child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    opacity: 1;
}
.performa-image-exit .performa-image-hover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.performa-image-exit:hover .performa-image-exit img{
    opacity: 0;
}
.performa-image-exit:hover .performa-image-hover {
    opacity: 1;
}


.performa-details-exit {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}

.performa-name-exit {
    font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #000;
    height: 36px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.performa-name-exit:hover {
    color: #d62598;
}
.performa-price-exit[data-discount="false"] {
    color: transparent;
}

.performa-price-exit {
    font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 32px;
    color: #666!important;
}

.performa-list-price-exit {
    font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #28cc00;
}

.performa-installments-exit, .performa-boleto-price-exit {
    font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: none;
    color: gray;
    padding: 3px 4px;
}

.la.la-credit-card {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Pro';
    font-weight: 400;
}

.la-credit-card:before {
    content: "\f09d";
}

.la.la-barcode {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Pro';
    font-weight: 400;
}

.la.la-barcode:before {
    content: "\f02a";
}


.performa-installments-exit i, .performa-boleto-price-exit i {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #d62598;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.performa-installments-exit strong, .performa-boleto-price-exit strong {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #d62598;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.performa-image-hover:hover{opacity:1}

.performa-installments-exit[data-installments="false"] {
    color: transparent;
}

.performa-installments-exit,
.performa-boleto-price-exit {
    font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: none;
    color: gray;
    padding: 3px 4px;
}
.performa-installments-exit i,
.performa-boleto-price-exit i{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #d62598;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    
}
.performa-installments-exit strong,
.performa-boleto-price-exit strong {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #d62598;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.performa-exit-comprarbtn {
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    margin: 20px auto 10px auto;
    font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.performa-exit-box:hover .performa-exit-comprarbtn {
    opacity: 1;
}

#pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf {
    width: calc(700%);
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    font-size: 0px;
}

@media (min-width: 0.0625em){
#pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf {
    width: calc(700%);
}}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao{
    width: 400px;
}}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<powerslider id="performa-powerslider_k4s2oxsup9" class="performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao performa-powersliderPopupk4s2oxsup9" style="display: block; background:#fff !important;">
<div class="performa-powerslider-content-exit-intent">
        <div id="pfm_s1jjcqiodfhze7qx" class="powerslider-root">
            <div class="tns-outer">
                <div class="tns-controls" aria-label="Carousel Navigation" tabindex="0">
                    <button data-controls="prev" id="prev" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf" type="button"></button>
                    <button data-controls="next" id="next" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="tns-inner tns-ovh" id="pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf-iw">
                    <ul id="pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf" style="display: block; list-style-type: disc; margin-block: 0px; margin-inline: 0px; padding-inline-start: 0px;" class=" tns-slider tns-carousel tns-subpixel tns-calc tns-horizontal">
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="0800451105">
                            <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="0800451105">
                                <a href="p/body-sem-bojo-com-aro-dina?attribute_pa_cores=sensualle&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=gg&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-1-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-1-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">1</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="0160192044">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="0160192044">
                                <a href="p/body-bicolor-camila?attribute_pa_cores=terra&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=g&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-2-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-2-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">2</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="0718916072">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="0718916072">
                                <a href="p/body-feminino-em-animal-print-branco?attribute_pa_cores=animal-print-branco&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=m&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-3-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-3-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">3</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="0201097042">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="0201097042">
                                <a href="p/body-em-veludo-com-tule?attribute_pa_cores=sensualle&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=m&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-4-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-4-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">4</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="2561232070">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="2561232070">
                                <a href="p/body-feminino-em-poliamida-fiona?attribute_pa_cores=preto&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=g&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-5-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-5-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">5</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="1285129052">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="1285129052">
                                <a href="p/body-em-renda-e-tule-morgana?attribute_pa_cores=preto&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=g&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-6-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-6-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">6</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="1236115704">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="1236115704">
                                <a href="p/body-em-tule-com-renda?attribute_pa_cores=preto&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=gg&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-7-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-7-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">7</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="2977698090">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="2977698090">
                                <a href="p/body-em-renda-com-desenho-geometrico-taina?attribute_pa_cores=branco&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=g&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-8-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-8-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">8</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="0919885058">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="0919885058">
                                <a href="p/body-com-detalhes-em-renda?attribute_pa_cores=branco&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=gg&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-9-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-9-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">9</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span id="conter_li" style="position:absolute;"></span>
</powerslider>
```

Galera estou precisando de um Help.

Criei um slide para mudança de imagem com botões para avançar e retroceder a imagem.

Como não tenho muita experiência em Jquery/Javascript, já peço desculpa antecipadas, porém foi isso que consegui fazer.

Coloquei um contador para saber em qual posição das imagens estavam sendo apresentada.

Até que o script está "funcionando" legalzinho, está avançando normal as imagens e quando chega na última, ele volta para a primeira imagem(0). Porém para retroceder a imagem funciona bem até chegar na primeira imagem(0), me perdi completamente.

Alguém consegue me dar uma ajudinha?

```js
var conter = 0;
qtos = $(".tns-carousel li").length/3;

//4.7619% - largura do li
//14.2857% - largura de 3 li

$("#next").click(function(e){
conter--;
counter = conter * 14.2857;
max = qtos * -14.2857;
if (counter == max){
    counter = 0;
    conter = 0;
}
$("#conter_li").html(counter);
$(".tns-carousel").css("transform","translate3d("+counter+"%, 0px, 0px)");
});

$("#prev").click(function(e){
conter++;
counter = conter * 14.2857;

if (counter > 0){
    counter = - 99.9999 + counter;
    conter = 6;
}

$("#conter_li").html(counter);
$(".tns-carousel").css("transform","translate3d("+counter+"%, 0px, 0px)");
});
```

Comment: no prev, que vai pra imangem anterior, não deveria diminuir? está somando (`conter++`)

Comment: Olá @RicardoPontual, agradeço por interagir. O botão NEXT faz as imagens "deslizarem" para trás, por isso o transform deve ser suntraído e o PREV faz o contrário, por isso deve ser somado

Comment: parece trocado o conceito, mas ok... se o "next" vai para trás, ele não deveria validar quando chega na 1a imagem, ou seja, `if (counter == 0)`? o `if (counter == max)` me parece que valida se chegou na última

Comment: no NEXT tem a validação if (counter == max) e está funcionando perfeitamente. O problema é no PREV

Comment: Coloquei todos os detalhes... HTML pra entender melhor

Answer (score -1):

Resolvido

```js
var conter = 0;
qtos = $(".tns-carousel li").length/3;
max = qtos * 14.2857;

$("#next").click(function(e){
conter++;
counter = -conter * 14.2857;
if (counter == -max){
    counter = 0;
    conter = 0;
}
$(".tns-carousel").css("transform","translate3d("+counter.toFixed(4)+"%, 0px, 0px)");
});

$("#prev").click(function(e){
conter--;
counter = conter * 14.2857;

if (counter < 0){
    counter = max - 14.2857;
    conter = qtos -1;
}

$(".tns-carousel").css("transform","translate3d("+ -counter.toFixed(4)+"%, 0px, 0px)");
});
```

```css
.performa-powersliderPopupecn1ml571r{position:fixed;top:calc(50% - 300px);left:calc(50% - 400px);display:none;width:800px;height:550px;background: #fff;z-index:100000000;animation-name: bounceIn;animation-duration: 450ms;animation-timing-function: linear;animation-fill-mode: forwards;animation-delay: 0s;-webkit-border-radius: 0px;-moz-border-radius: 0px;border-radius: 0px;}.performa-powerslider-close-intent{height: 40px;width: 40px;right: -20px;top: -20px;position: absolute;background: #000;border: 3px solid #fff;border-radius: 1000px;cursor: pointer;}.performa-powerslider-close-intent span{font-family: calibri, sans-serif;color: #fff;font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 38px;padding: 11px;top: 0px;vertical-align: middle;position: relative;box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;}.performa-powersliderPopupImgecn1ml571r{position:relative;float:lefttop:0px;left:0px;-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;-moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;border-top-left-radius: 0px;border-top-right-radius: 0px;}.performa-powersliderPopupFadeecn1ml571r{position:fixed;left:0px;top:0px;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;background:#000;opacity:0.7;display:none;z-index:99999999;}.performa-powerslider-bounce {-webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;animation: bounce 2s infinite;}@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn {0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0); }40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); }60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-15px); }}@-moz-keyframes bounceIn {0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0); }40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); }60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-15px); }}@keyframes bounceIn {0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);-moz-transform: translateY(0);-ms-transform: translateY(0);-o-transform: translateY(0);transform: translateY(0);}40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);-moz-transform: translateY(-30px);-ms-transform: translateY(-30px);-o-transform: translateY(-30px);transform: translateY(-30px);}60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);-moz-transform: translateY(-15px);-ms-transform: translateY(-15px);-o-transform: translateY(-15px);transform: translateY(-15px);}}.performa-powerslider-content-exit-intent {width:100%;position:absolute;overflow:hidden;}.powerSlider-exit-brand {    position: absolute;    bottom: -25px;       float: right;    width: 100%;}.powerSlider-exit-brand img {float: right;}.prevBtn {    position: absolute;    top: calc(50% - 25px);    left: 20px;    width: 30px;    height: 30px;    transform: rotate(45deg);    border: none;    background-color: transparent;    border-bottom: 4px solid #6b6b6b;    border-left: 4px solid #6b6b6b;}.nextBtn {    position: absolute;    top: calc(50% - 25px);    right: 20px;    width: 30px;    height: 30px;    transform: rotate(45deg);    border: none;    background-color: transparent;    border-top: 4px solid #6b6b6b;    border-right: 4px solid #6b6b6b;}.nextBtn:focus,.prevBtn:focus {    outline: none;}/*******************************
FIX LAYOUT CONTAINER EXIT INTENT
*******************************/
.performa-item-exit a:hover, .performa-item-exit a:visited, .performa-item-exit a:link, .performa-item-exit a:active, .performa-item-exit a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}

.performa-powersliderPopupk4s2oxsup9 {
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(50% - 300px);
    left: calc(50% - 400px);
    display: none;
    width: 800px;
    height: 550px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 100000000;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-duration: 450ms;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao {
    padding: 15px  10px !important;    
    border-radius: 20px !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    width: 900px !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    margin: auto;
}

.performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao > img {
    border-radius: 20px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center top;
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}

.performa-powersliderPopupImgk4s2oxsup9 {
    position: relative;
    float: lefttop:0px;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}

powerslider *, powerslider :after, powerslider :before {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    line-height: 1;
    list-style: none;
    quotes: none;
    content: '';
    content: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.performa-powerslider-content-exit-intent {
    width: auto !important;
    position: relative !important;
    margin: 130px 30px 0 !important;
    overflow: unset !important;
}

.performa-powerslider-close-intent {
    height: 25px !important;
    width: 25px !important;
    right: 10px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    border: unset !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

.performa-powerslider-close-intent span {
    font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 11px;
    top: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.performa-powerslider-close-intent span {
    color: #d62598 !important;
}

.performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao .tns-controls button[data-controls=prev] {
    left: -25px !important;
}

.performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao .tns-controls button[data-controls=next] {
    right: -25px !important;
}

#pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf-iw {
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.tns-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tns-controls {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.tns-outer {
    position: relative;
}

#pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf > .tns-item {
    width: calc(4.7619%);
}

#pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf > .tns-item {
    font-size: 14px;
}


.tns-controls button {
    position: absolute;
    background: 0 0;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    border-left: 2px solid;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 40%;
    z-index: 1;
    outline: 0;
}

.tns-controls button[data-controls=prev] {
    left: 15px;
}

.tns-controls button[data-controls=next] {
    right: 15px;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao .tns-controls button {
    color: #d62598 !important;
    width: 25px !important;
    height: 25px !important;
    border-bottom: 4px solid !important;
    border-left: 4px solid !important;
    border-radius: unset !important;
    background: transparent !important;
}

.performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao .tns-controls button:before {
    box-shadow: unset !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    border-radius: unset !important;
    color: transparent !important;
}

/****************
**SLIDER VITRINE**
****************/
.performa-exit-ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.performa-exit-ul .performa-item-exit {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.performa-item-exit a:hover,
.performa-item-exit a:visited,
.performa-item-exit a:link,
.performa-item-exit a:active,
.performa-item-exit a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}

.performa-exit-box {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    margin-right: 20px;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.performa-exit-box:hover {
}

.performa-exit-box a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.performa-flags-exit {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.performa-flag-discount-exit {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 65px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #000;
    font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
}

.performa-image-exit {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.performa-image-exit img:first-child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    opacity: 1;
}
.performa-image-exit .performa-image-hover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.performa-image-exit:hover .performa-image-exit img{
    opacity: 0;
}
.performa-image-exit:hover .performa-image-hover {
    opacity: 1;
}


.performa-details-exit {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}

.performa-name-exit {
    font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #000;
    height: 36px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.performa-name-exit:hover {
    color: #d62598;
}
.performa-price-exit[data-discount="false"] {
    color: transparent;
}

.performa-price-exit {
    font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 32px;
    color: #666!important;
}

.performa-list-price-exit {
    font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #28cc00;
}

.performa-installments-exit, .performa-boleto-price-exit {
    font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: none;
    color: gray;
    padding: 3px 4px;
}

.la.la-credit-card {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Pro';
    font-weight: 400;
}

.la-credit-card:before {
    content: "\f09d";
}

.la.la-barcode {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Pro';
    font-weight: 400;
}

.la.la-barcode:before {
    content: "\f02a";
}


.performa-installments-exit i, .performa-boleto-price-exit i {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #d62598;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.performa-installments-exit strong, .performa-boleto-price-exit strong {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #d62598;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.performa-image-hover:hover{opacity:1}

.performa-installments-exit[data-installments="false"] {
    color: transparent;
}

.performa-installments-exit,
.performa-boleto-price-exit {
    font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: none;
    color: gray;
    padding: 3px 4px;
}
.performa-installments-exit i,
.performa-boleto-price-exit i{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #d62598;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    
}
.performa-installments-exit strong,
.performa-boleto-price-exit strong {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #d62598;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.performa-exit-comprarbtn {
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    margin: 20px auto 10px auto;
    font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.performa-exit-box:hover .performa-exit-comprarbtn {
    opacity: 1;
}

#pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf {
    width: calc(700%);
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    font-size: 0px;
}

@media (min-width: 0.0625em){
#pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf {
    width: calc(700%);
}}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao{
    width: 400px;
}}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<powerslider id="performa-powerslider_k4s2oxsup9" class="performa-powersliderpopup-personalizacao performa-powersliderPopupk4s2oxsup9" style="display: block; background:#fff !important;">
<div class="performa-powerslider-content-exit-intent">
        <div id="pfm_s1jjcqiodfhze7qx" class="powerslider-root">
            <div class="tns-outer">
                <div class="tns-controls" aria-label="Carousel Navigation" tabindex="0">
                    <button data-controls="prev" id="prev" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf" type="button"></button>
                    <button data-controls="next" id="next" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf" type="button"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="tns-inner tns-ovh" id="pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf-iw">
                    <ul id="pfm_gbneo7ra20vtlrdf" style="display: block; list-style-type: disc; margin-block: 0px; margin-inline: 0px; padding-inline-start: 0px;" class=" tns-slider tns-carousel tns-subpixel tns-calc tns-horizontal">
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="0800451105">
                            <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="0800451105">
                                <a href="p/body-sem-bojo-com-aro-dina?attribute_pa_cores=sensualle&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=gg&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-1-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-1-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">1</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="0160192044">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="0160192044">
                                <a href="p/body-bicolor-camila?attribute_pa_cores=terra&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=g&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-2-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-2-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">2</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="0718916072">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="0718916072">
                                <a href="p/body-feminino-em-animal-print-branco?attribute_pa_cores=animal-print-branco&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=m&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-3-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-3-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">3</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="0201097042">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="0201097042">
                                <a href="p/body-em-veludo-com-tule?attribute_pa_cores=sensualle&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=m&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-4-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-4-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">4</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="2561232070">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="2561232070">
                                <a href="p/body-feminino-em-poliamida-fiona?attribute_pa_cores=preto&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=g&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-5-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-5-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">5</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="1285129052">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="1285129052">
                                <a href="p/body-em-renda-e-tule-morgana?attribute_pa_cores=preto&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=g&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-6-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-6-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">6</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="1236115704">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="1236115704">
                                <a href="p/body-em-tule-com-renda?attribute_pa_cores=preto&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=gg&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-7-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-7-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">7</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="2977698090">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="2977698090">
                                <a href="p/body-em-renda-com-desenho-geometrico-taina?attribute_pa_cores=branco&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=g&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-8-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-8-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">8</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="performa-item-exit tns-item" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top !important;" data-composite="" data-id="0919885058">
                           <div class="performa-exit-box" data-id="0919885058">
                                <a href="p/body-com-detalhes-em-renda?attribute_pa_cores=branco&amp;attribute_pa_tamanho=gg&amp;utm_source=Performa&amp;utm_medium=PowerSlider">
                                    <div class="performa-image-exit">
                                            <img class="tns-lazy-img" src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-9-PNG.png" data-src="https://cdn-0.imagensemoldes.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Foto-Numero-9-PNG.png">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="performa-details-exit">
                                        <span class="performa-name-exit">9</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                           </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</powerslider>
```